# Is it possible to know if a setState was called at least once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form I am updating some fields with, but I would not like to send the updated fields unless they have been updated. I am controlling the form state for the inputs with some `useState` like so:

```
const [description, setDescription] = useState(
  data?.description ?? '',
);
```

When the user clicks the submission button, I want to send only the form inputs that were updated - so I am wondering if it is possible to know if the setState function was called at all. So it would be something like :

```
 let submission = {};
  if(*setDescription was called*) {
  submission.description = description
}
 commit(submission);
```

I was originally thinking of just doing :

```
 let submission = {};
  if(description !== data?.description) {
  submission.description = description
}
 commit(submission);
```

but the data gets mutated a bit on certain inputs, so it's a pain to pull out the values and compared them. Is something like this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You could wrap the `setState` calls and set a flag. Or fancier: write your own hook that does this.

Comment: @xehpuk I think hook might be the way to go for wrapping + reuse. Thanks!

Comment: An easy way would just be to use the useEffect hook and set the dependency to whatever state you want to detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom hook with a flag should do the trick:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function useTrackedState(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const setTrackedState = (...args) => {
    setTrackedState.wasSet = true
    return setState(...args)
  }

  setTrackedState.wasSet = false

  return [state, setTrackedState]
}
```

From your example:

```
const [description, setDescription] = useTrackedState(
  data?.description ?? '',
);

// ...

let submission = {};
if (setDescription.wasSet) {
  submission.description = description
}
commit(submission);
```